# How usable is Groovy++?

Tags: groovy

How usable is [Groovy++](http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/wiki/Welcome)? Could I start using it today without major problems with getting it working? Does it have a lot of bugs?  Does it integrate nicely with eclipse?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How usable is Groovy++?

It's getting there, evidenced by the fact that there's now a grails plugin.

> Could I start using it today without major problems with getting it working?

That depends on what you'll be doing with it, I imagine. You could probably swap out Groovy jars with Groovy++ without noticing any immediate differences. It's really a matter of how much you use @Typed.

> Does it have a lot of bugs?

[Issues](http://code.google.com/p/groovypptest/issues/list).

> Does it integrate nicely with eclipse?

I don't see why not, but to be honest, I've not attempted it recently.

The real answer to all of these questions is complicated by the furious pace of development.  Groovy++ is still a young project that literally changes from one day to the next.  Thus, bugs appear and get squashed in short order. If you're to use it, it'd probably be wise to setup a means of automatically updating your version, lest you go insane.

The general consensus suggests that Groovy++ is not yet ready for prime-time. But, if the current level of activity is sustained, it should soon be viable. (Though, I suspect many people are waiting for Groovy and Groovy++ to merge at some date unknown)